# Keyboard not working on asus zenbook Q408UG 211

Tags: keyboard, asus, 22.04

I'm trying to install ubuntu for the first time, from a flash drive, but when I go into the try ubuntu mode, my keyboard doesn't work.

I've read that I can use the virtual keyboard to run this command on the terminal (sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all) and it should work after rebooting the system, but I don't think this is applicable if I'm trying the system, and I won't install unless I'm sure it will work correctly.

What can I do? I'm a total novice sorry if this is a bad question or too obvious of an answer.

Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and encountered the same issue.  The installer does not recognize the built-in keyboard.  I tried multiple variants of Linux and encountered the problem on all the variants.

However, if you install using an external keyboard, the laptop's keyboard works fine after the install is complete.  I'm currently running Xubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I just got the Vivobook S14 and the keyboard is not detected even after install. I'm forced to type this with an external keyboard.

Comment: I think the fixes are now added to latest Ubuntu kernel releases, I am using Ubuntu 22.10 with kernel version 5.19.0.28.29 and the Keyboard issue now resolved,